# Using php in jboss

Tags: php, jsp, jboss

I have a php file(demo.php) and a jsp file(news.jsp). demo.php sends the updates to news.jsp using Server sent events(SSE). I am using jboss4.0.2 as my web application server. I have worked only with jsp and servlets before in jboss. I know to modify web.xml(In WEB-INF) file for jsp file(same directory as WEB-INF) and servlets(In WEB-INF/classes).Where should i deploy the php file and what changes are necessary in jboss to do the same.

Comment: Is the PHP script a console program or do you neeed a web browser to use it?

Comment: @JoniSalonen:The php file is used as a server for sending server sent events(SSE) to jsp file described above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does, . See http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/modules/php/index.html.

Basically, you need to more things:

1) JBoss Native - download and install the one specific to your operating system

2) The PHP module - download and configure as indicated in the above link.

3) You must package your PHP app within a WAR file. The PHP module download comes with a demo PHP WAR file, use that as a template.

Comment: Link is broken and can you update the link to http://jbossweb.jboss.org/modules/php.html